# If a variable is modified to reference a different AtomicLong, will the update be visible then?

Tags: java

If I am doing something like this in a class-

```
private AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0);
```

and then inside a method, I do this-

```
 count = new AtomicLong(1); // will this update is going to be visible to other threads
```

I am confused because `AtomicLong` is `@ThreadSafe`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're completely missing the point of `AtomicLong`.

`AtomicLong` provides methods to manipulate it in a thread-safe manner.
Replacing your instance with a new instance bypasses all of those.

You should make all `AtomicLong` variables `final` to prevent that.

You also need to make sure that you don't try to read the same value twice, because other threads could change it between your reads.  See [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures/) for more on thread-safe code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand why `AtomicLong` is thread safe. Being thread safe means that no external synchronization is required when calling it's methods. In other words, all threads will see the correct value of the long variable stored in it.

When you use the `new` operator, you will create a new instance of that class so it's possible that one thread may see the value from the initial declaration and another will see the new value.

Answer (score 2):

How can an instance guarantee thread safety if you are destroying its instance and create a new one? Actually, it is the instance guaranteeing this... not the class.

Actually this will break the thread safety, because there is no difference between

```
private AtomicLong count = new Long(0);
count = new AtomicLong (1);
```

and

```
private Long count = new Long(0);
count = new Long(1);
```

Because you are changing the *instances*.

`AtomicLong` is only guaranteed to be thread-safe if you keep the instance. Therefore you should just do:

```
count.incrementAndGet()
```

or

```
count.set(1)
```

Thus keeping the instance and therefore the thread safety.